# Caching data within a Python class (to avoid expensive filesystem reads on App Engine)

Tags: python, google-app-engine

This question isn't entirely App Engine specific, but it might help knowing the context: I have a kind of "static site generator" on App Engine that renders pages and allows them to be styled via various themes and theme settings. The themes are currently stored directly on the App Engine filesystem and uploaded with the application. A theme consists of a few templates and yaml configuration data.

To encapsulate working with themes, I have a `Theme` class. `theme = Theme('sunshine')`, for example, constructs a Theme instance that loads and parses the configuration data of the theme called 'sunshine', and allows calls like `theme.render_template('index.html')` that automatically load and render the correct file on the filesystem.

Problem is, loading and especially parsing a Theme's (yaml) configuration data every time a new request comes in and instantiates a `Theme` is expensive. So, I want to cache the data within the processes/App Engine instances and maybe later within memcached.

Until now, I've used very simple caches like so:

```
class Theme(object):
     _theme_variables_cache = {}

     def __init__(self, name):
         self.name = name

         if name not in Theme._theme_variables_cache:
             Theme._theme_variables[name] = self.load_theme_variables()

...
```

*(I'm aware that the config could be read multiple times when several requests hit the constructor at the same time. I don't think it causes problems though.)*

But that kind of caching gets ugly really quickly. I have several different things I want to read from config files and all of the caches are dictionaries because every different theme 'name' also points to a different underlying configuration.

The last idea I had was creating a function like `Theme._cached_func(func)` that will only execute func when the functions result isn't already cached for the specific template (remember, when the object represents a different template, the cached value can also be different). So I could use it like: `self.theme_variables = Theme._cached_func(self.load_theme_variables())`, but, I have a feeling I'm missing something obvious here as I'm still pretty new to Python.

Is there an obvious and clean Python caching pattern that will work for such a situation without cluttering up the entire class with cache logic? I think I can't just memoize function results via decorators or something because different templates will have to have different caches. I don't even need any "stale" cache handling because the underlying configuration data doesn't change while a process runs.

**Update**

I ended up doing it like that:

```
class ThemeConfig(object):
    __instances_cache = {}

    @classmethod
    def get_for(cls, theme_name):
        return cls.__instances_cache.setdefault(
            theme_name, ThemeConfig(theme_name))

    def __init__(self, theme_name):
        self.theme_name = theme_name
        self._load_assets_urls()  # those calls load yaml files
        self._load_variables()
...


class Theme(object):
    def __init__(self, theme_name):
        self.theme_name = theme_name
        self.config = ThemeConfig.get_for(theme_name)
...
```

So `ThemeConfig` stores all the configuration stuff that's read from the filesystem for a theme and the factory method `ThemeConfig.get_for` will always hand out the same ThemeConfig instance for the same theme name. The only caching logic I have is the one line in the factory method, and `Theme` objects are still as temporary and non-shared as they always were, so I can use and abuse them however I wish.

Comment: Have a look at the caching mechanism in webapp2.cached_property. You can implement a dict using a similar design.

Comment: @siebz0r as far as I understand, webapp2.cached_property modifies a property so that its evaluation replaces it by its result, so that the next lookup will just get the result without even calling the method, right? I guess I could somehow patch it so it checks whether the same method was already called on a Theme object referring to the same theme name, and then just return the cached result. But I feel like this is a bit too much magic. Not sure if I could still remember what I did two weeks later. Or did you have something else in mind?

Comment: cached_property only caches within a single request, so probably isn't useful in this scenario

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will take a shot at this. Basically, a factory pattern can be used here to maintain a clean boundary between your **Theme** object and the creation of the **Theme** instance with a particular way.

The factory itself can also maintain a simple caching strategy by storing a mapping between the **Theme** name and the corresponding **Theme** object. I would go with a following implementation:

```
#the ThemeFactory class instantiates a Theme with a particular name if not present within it's cache
class ThemeFactory(object) :

     def __init__(self):
         self.__theme_variables_cache = {}

     def createTheme(self, theme_name):
         if not self.__theme_variables_cache.contains(name):
              theme = Theme(theme_name)
              self.__theme_variables_cache[name] = theme.load_theme_variables()
          return self.__theme_variables_cache[name]
```

The definition of the **Theme** class is now very clean and simple and will not contain any caching complications

```
class Theme(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.__theme_name = name

    def load_theme_variables(self):
        #contain the logic for loading theme variables from theme files
```

The approach has the advantages of code maintainability and clear segregation of responsibilities ( although not completely so , the factory class still maintains the simple cache. Ideally it should simply have a reference to a caching service or another class that handles caching .. but you get the point).

Your **Theme** class does what it does the best - loading theme variables. Since you have a factory pattern, you are keeping the client code ( the one that consumes the **Theme** class instance) encapsulated from the logic of creating the **Theme** instances. As your application grows, you can extend this factory to control the creation of various **Theme** objects (including classes derived fron **Theme**)

Note that this is just one way of achieving simple caching behavior as well as instance creation encapsulation.

One more point - you could store **Theme** objects within the cache instead of the theme variables. This way you could read the theme variables from templates **only on first use**(lazy loading). However, in this case you would need to make sure that you store the theme variables as an instance variable of the **Theme** class. The method `load_theme_variables(self)` now needs to be written this way:

```
def load_theme_variables(self):
   #let the theme variables be stored in an instance variable __theme_variable
   if not self.__theme_variables is None:
       return self.__theme_variables
    #__read_theme_file is a private function that reads the theme files
   self__theme_variables = self.__read_theme_file(self.__theme_name)
```

Hopefully, this gives you an idea on how to go about achieving your use case.

Comment: Do take notice that this is caching to the ThemeFactory instance not to the class. This means you've got to keep a ThemeFactory instance to keep the cache. Why not add a classmethod to the Theme class that caches to the Theme  class. Factory classes are so Java ;-)

Comment: @siebz0r wait, how would the cache disappear? In my (still relatively limited) understanding of Python, all references would still be valid for as long as I hold them, even if the creator of the referenced object is long gone. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: @PrahaladDeshpande thanks. The reason why I didn't want to cache the Theme objects themselves was that I still wasn't sure if the Theme will always be just a read-only representation of a Theme, or have some kind of (admittedly temporary) state that can be worked with. I kinda like the factory idea, although I'm not quite sure I understand why createTheme returns the cached result of load_theme_variables.

Comment: Don't cache anything that is modified at runtime in a scheme like this. Only the instance that made the modification will ever see the result.  All other instances already running will never see the change. Use memcache for modifiable cached entities

Comment: @Confield you can invalidate the cache using a post delete hook thus keeping sync with the datastore.

Comment: @TimHoffman I only need to cache a theme's configuration data that I read and parse from the filesystem and that doesn't changes at runtime. As I described, my `Theme` class is just a temporary pointer that encapsulates working with Themes. You say `theme = Theme('themename')` and from that moment on all operations on that object will reference 'themename's configuration, 'themename's template files, etc. My only problem was that reading the config stuff is expensive, and caching multiple values/properties on a class that can represent several different themes gets messy easily.

Comment: Just providing a warning - as there was a comment about temporary state.  I cache custom yaml configs all the time.  Just load and store in a module level attribute - I don't even bother with a class.  But in the end thats the same end result.

Comment: @TimHoffman and that warning is well received. When I talked about temporary state I just meant that I don't want a Factory that hands out the same objects for the same themes over and over again. That would solve loading the configuration only once for every theme, but it also prevents me from making the Theme objects do stuff that requires some temporary state that should never be shared in any way.

Comment: @Confield It is ok, if we do not cache the Theme object themselves. I just provided that approach in my answer to specify another perspective towards the problem. This works well if and only if Theme are read-only. However, as you mentioned within your comment Themes may contain temporary state and hence in that case, Theme instances must not be cached.createTheme returns cached result of load_theme_variables , since as per my understanding, this method loads the theme configuration variables which can be cached.

Comment: Thanks guys. I updated my question with the solution I ended up using.   I based it on Prahalad Deshpande's suggestion to use a factory that hands out shared objects, but with the modification that I moved all the configuration to a seperate sub-object so I can still have temporary and non-shared state on `Theme` instances.